# Update Query With Nested Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

Here, I have some student Information In table. Whose authorized value is by default 0.
After checking some condition i group some students and update there value to 1.

Only those students who meets the given condition i.e.

```
select * from studentA 
where schName ='IES DADAR' and lang = 'E' 

[1]: http://rk.somee.com/untitled.jpg
```

I am trying with the following code but its not filtering as per my given condition, instead it changes every students authorization value to 1.

```
update studentA
set Authorized = '1'
where Authorized IN 
( select Authorized from studentA 
where schName ='IES DADAR' and lang = 'E')
```

You can suggest me another method as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
update studentA 
set Authorized = '1' 
where schName ='IES DADAR' 
and lang = 'E'
```

Answer (score 2):

The subquery

```
 select Authorized from studentA 
 where schName ='IES DADAR' and lang = 'E'
```

returns 0 and so your actual query becomes

```
update studentA
set Authorized = '1'
where Authorized IN ('0')
```

thereby updating every row in the table.

So, it should be

```
update studentA
set Authorized = '1'
where schName ='IES DADAR' and lang = 'E'
```